# Spring конфиг, проблема с профилями

Tags: spring

Если запускаю приложение со spring1.xml вылетает ошибка

> "No qualifying bean of type
>   'arkhipov.bank.repositories.UserRepository' available"

а если со spring2.xml, то работает. Запускаю с параметром "--spring.profiles.active=postgres". В чем может быть проблема?

spring1.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <beans profile="h2,postgres">
        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
            <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/data.sql"/>
        </jdbc:initialize-database>

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
              p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
              p:packagesToScan="arkhipov.bank">

            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                      p:databasePlatform="${jpa.databasePlatform}"
                      p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="arkhipov.bank.repositories"/>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="arkhipov.bank.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                          transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="h2">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/h2.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
              p:url="${database.url}"
              p:username="${database.username}"
              p:password="${database.password}"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="postgres">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              p:url="${database.url}"
              p:username="${database.username}"
              p:password="${database.password}"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

spring2.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!--<beans profile="h2,postgres">-->
        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${database.init}">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:db/${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
            <jdbc:script encoding="utf-8" location="classpath:db/data.sql"/>
        </jdbc:initialize-database>

        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
              p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
              p:packagesToScan="arkhipov.bank">

            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                      p:databasePlatform="${jpa.databasePlatform}"
                      p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
              p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="arkhipov.bank.repositories"/>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="arkhipov.bank.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                          transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    <!--</beans>-->

    <!--<beans profile="h2">-->
        <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/h2.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>-->

        <!--<bean id="dataSource"-->
              <!--class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"-->
              <!--p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"-->
              <!--p:url="${database.url}"-->
              <!--p:username="${database.username}"-->
              <!--p:password="${database.password}"/>-->
    <!--</beans>-->

    <!--<beans profile="postgres">-->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              p:url="${database.url}"
              p:username="${database.username}"
              p:password="${database.password}"/>
    <!--</beans>-->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте запускать так:
-Dspring.profiles.active=postgres

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Глупая была ошибка:)